# scrollbar on browser and div margin 0 auto jumping

Tags: html, css

i am using div#wrapper `margin: 0 auto` to center the div, there is scroll bar on this page however when it transition to second page where there is no scroll bar, it appears as jumpy because there is no scroll bar i guess.

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="wrapper">
....

#wrapper { width: 970px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

what would be the best solution for this not to make it jumpy?

Comment: the best solution is NOT to center your wrapper. Scroll bar is part of your browser, and by adding it you re-size your HTML rendering area.

Answer (score 12):

Set html width to be equal viewport and turn off horizontal scroll to avoid appearing of horizontal scrollbar when vertical one will expand html.

```
html {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could give this code 1000 points. I have been trying to resolve an issue for hours now and this is the solution. I had some strange jumping behaviour on my website (bootstrap based) when the direction is RTL. On page load, the content appears for 1/10 second on far right then jumps to center (as should by `margin: 0 auto`) and the `col-md-3` width applied on delay. This `css` fixed all those issues, why, no idea :-)

Answer (score 6):

I've run into this a few times, the best thing I've found is to force a **Y scroll-bar** on every page, even if it isn't needed using in your style sheet:

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

This will mean there is always a right scroll bar on the page, but it will be enabled/disabled as needed, and prevent the jump.

Comment: For some reason it only worked when I added that style to body, not html

Answer (score 3):

Adding a calculated margin to your html tag will create a margin on the left equal to the scrollbar on the right if a scrollbar exists.  This will stop the jumping.

```
html { 
    margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%); 
}
```

[Original Source](https://aykevl.nl/2014/09/fix-jumping-scrollbar)

Comment: This is the cleverest and the most consistent answer. I've applied such styling to `body`, though (`body { margin: 0; margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%); }`).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to force a Y scroll-bar on every page, you can calculate the margins using view-port width. This stopped the auto jumping for me.

```
@media (min-width: 960px) {
    .container {
        margin-left: calc(50vw - 480px);
        width: 960px;
    }
}
```