# Overflow-y: auto hopping scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a container with `overflow-y: auto;`. Is there any way to solve hopping of content, because of scrollbar change `width` of container?

Ideal would be these options:

- Animated change `width` of container, when scrollbar disappear.
- Render container with `width: calc(100vw - scrollBarHeight)` when there is no scrollbar.

But how?

Here's a demonstration:

```js
let longText = "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."

let shortText = "Hello human!"

let content = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
let button = document.getElementsByClassName('change-content')[0];

let currentContent = 0;

let changeContent = () => {
  currentContent++;
  content.innerHTML = currentContent % 2 ? shortText : longText;
}

button.onclick = changeContent;

changeContent();
```

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button class="change-content">Change</button>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="menu"></nav>
  <section class="content"></section>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27yuLbw7/1/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent scrollbar from repositioning web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417934/how-to-prevent-scrollbar-from-repositioning-web-page) Also see [Content jumps horizontally whenever browser adds a scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201968/content-jumps-horizontally-whenever-browser-adds-a-scrollbar). Also see [scrollbar on browser and div margin 0 auto jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357870/scrollbar-on-browser-and-div-margin-0-auto-jumping).